# Adding two button via coding in viewDidLoad section is always hiding one button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Adding two button via coding in `viewDidLoad` section is always hiding one button, and I don't know why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //array initialization

    list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    heading=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 20.0f)];
    heading.text=@"Lists";
    heading.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:heading];

    UIImage *addButton=[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
    add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    add.frame = CGRectMake(190.0f, 6.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(addList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [add setImage:addButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:add];

    UIImage *contact=[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"];
    UIButton *cntctBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    add.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 6.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(shareContact) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [add setImage:contact forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:cntctBtn];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a copy and paste error. You never set the frame, image, or target action for the second button because you have "add" where you should have "cntctBtn".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //array initialization

    list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    heading=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 20.0f)];
    heading.text=@"Lists";
    heading.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:heading];

    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addButton.frame = CGRectMake(190.0f, 6.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview: addButton];

    UIImage *contact=[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"];
    UIButton *cntctBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cntctBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 6.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    [cntctBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(shareContact) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cntctBtn setImage:contact forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:cntctBtn];
}
```

Its a copy paste error. Above is the corrected code.

Comment: you are into iPhone app development?I am a beginner now.So facing lot of problem like this.

Comment: When I am running the code the image of second button is showing in the 1st button and the second button image is not showing.But when I am disabling the code of second button the image of 1st button is showing correctly.What's the problem?
@Schemetrical

Comment: @KoustovBasu make sure your variables are in the right place. Proofread your code more.